# Failed assertion: line 135 pos 12: '_route == ModalRoute.of(context)': FlutterBuenas

Tags: firebase, flutter

estoy terminando mi proyecto final de DAM, y estoy teniendo muchos problemas con Flutter y Fireabase ya que han actualizado nuevos metodos, me salta ese error cuando, tengo un drawer de menu y es cuando pulso cerrar sesion la cual, cuando la clicas esta vinculada a un metodo signOut(). Salta ese error, espero que me puedan ayudar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de signOut() es el siguiente:

[image: iEl código de signOut() es el siguiente:]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Para mejor legibilidad, pon el código _como texto, con formato_. Al editar tu pregunta, puedes darle formato con el botón que indica `{}` o pon tres tildes invertidas (`) tanto al principio como al final del código.

Answer (score 0):

````
```
 void _signOut() async {
        await _auth.signOut();
 }

  void signOut(context) async {
    final User user = await _auth.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      Get.snackbar('Out', 'No one has signed in.',
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
      return;
    }
    _signOut();
    final String uid = user.uid;
    Get.snackbar('Out', uid + ' has successfully signed out.',
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen()));
  }
```
````